# Async and await not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I'm attempting to learn and use async - await - promise, but I'm getting a syntax error "Undefined token function" referring to the line where I define my async function. I check for an open bracket, but they all appear to be fine.

How do I get this to work?

**------ Update -----**

**-- Handler that's getting fired --**

```
const NumberIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'NumberIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
      let slotNum = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.number.value;
      //var myRequest = parseInt(slotNum);   
      const myRequest = parseInt(slotNum);
      console.log('NumberIntentHandler myRequest: ', myRequest);
      const options = `http://numbersapi.com/${myRequest}`;
      console.log('NumberIntentHandler options: ', options);

      // Use the async function
  const myResult = await httpGet(options)
         console.log("sent     : " + options);
         console.log("received : " + myResult);
         const speechText = myResult;
         console.log('speechText: ', speechText); // Print the speechText   */ 

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
           .speak(speechText)
           .withSimpleCard('Here is your fact: ', speechText)
           .getResponse(); 
  },
};
```

**-- Function that's getting called from the Handler --**

```
async function httpGet(options) {
  // return new pending promise
  console.log(`~~~~~~~~ httpGetPromise ~~~~~~~~~`);
  console.log(`~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~${JSON.stringify(options)}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);


  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = http.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
      // handle http errors
      if (response < 200 || response > 299) {
        reject(new Error('Failed to load page, status code: ' + response));
      }

    });
    // handle connection errors of the request
    request.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
    request.end();
  });
}
```

**Log of Error I'm getting**

[image]

Comment: IIRC async can only be used with statically defined functions. Try switching it to `const httpGet = async (options) => { //your code }}`

Comment: @AlexDovzhanyn What do you mean by "statically defined"? No, one does not need arrow functions.

Comment: @Hackbrew Can you please post your complete file?

Comment: Btw, you forgot to call `resolve` in your promise executor

Comment: @Bergi i didnt say they needed arrow functions, i just added those in. By statically defined i meant variable assignment vs function definition. Notice in my code I'm assigning the function to a var whereas they're defining the function using the keyword

Comment: @AlexDovzhanyn OK, but still no. `async function` declarations work just fine.

Comment: @Hackbrew what environment are you running this code in, node.js? What version? Does it support `async`/`await` syntax at all?

Comment: @Bergi - I ran Node -v and it shows v6.11.1

Comment: @Hackbrew Then [that's your problem](https://node.green/). Update to 7 or newer.

Comment: @Bergi - Yes that eliminated the syntax error.  But while I'm making the request, my return statement is evaluated and therefore speechText hasn't been set yet.  You also mentioned that I forgot to call `resolve` in my promise executor.  Not sure how to do that?

Comment: Instead of printing `error`, `response` and `body` to the console, resolve (or reject) your promise with them by calling the respective callback.

Comment: You will then want to use `const myResult = await httpGet(myRequest)`, instead of passing a callback

Comment: @Bergi - Sorry, I missed your earlier post regarding posting the complete file, so I update the code to include everything.  I also noticed that I have an issue with the way I'm defining the options for the path parameter with myData `path: "${myData}"`.

Comment: thanks, complete file wasn't necessary any more after we identified your problem to be the node version.

Comment: @Bergi - With having the complete code, the issue is my one handler "NumberIntentHandler" which now calls the async function "httpGet". How do I get this function to work?

Comment: Make the `handle` method `async` and use `await` with the `httpGet` call, instead of a callback.

Comment: @Bergi - Updated the code to only include the issue.

Comment: Why does `httpGet` call itself? And why are you passing the result of `parseInt` to `httpGet` instead of an options object?

Comment: @Bergi - Mainly because I'm not familiar with javascript and/or asyncronous programming, but I thank you for working me threw this.  I updated the code with the error I'm now getting.

Comment: I think you really should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that specific problem instead of constantly editing this one. Also please don't post error messages as screenshots.